# Are there PHP bindings for indicators and notifications?

Tags: python, indicator, php, notify-osd

Are there already some projects/extensions or wrappers to allow easy creation of ubuntu unity indicators with PHP before I try and 'reinvent the wheel'.

A basic Python template that would interface with a PHP class would be ideal. E.g, to map context menus to php functions and to define the 'main loop' (like GLUT for c++).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there exists any. Although I would like to know why anyone would like to have php binding that actually makes the use of the python wrapper.

Comment: I am half-way through making my own python wrapper now. The only reason I want this is because I find writing/reading/re-using PHP far easier than Python code. Python is a fantastic/powerful language, but it's not for me. I only use Python when something is not available for me in PHP which is fairly rare.

Comment: But then it would restrict application to unix environment only. I also find most of the time comfortable with php. When you are done with the wrapper let us know. Good Luck.